# How can I find unique fields in a CSV file?

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have a CSV file with 5 columns: 
`name firstname phone room email`

I did a script to display the phone number of each persons and I want to modify it to display the persons that are alone in a room.

for example

- Dan;B;;B10.12;;
- Liz;B;;B10.12;;
- Jer;B;;C15.1;;

I should only get `Jer B C15.1` as result.

There is what I'm trying to do but I don't know how to only take the rooms where there is 1 person. I would also like to display the result in the terminal.

```
input="collaborateurs.csv"
while read line; do
    room=$(echo $line | cut -d \; -f 4)
    if [ -n "$room" ]; then
        firstname=$(echo $line | cut -d \; -f 2)
        name=$(echo $line | cut -d \; -f 1)
        echo "${firstname} ${name} -> ${room}"
    fi
done < ${input}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to grep each room, sort the data and get the unique rooms. If a room has exactly one occurrence, it is stored in the `UNIQUE` array:

```sh
UNIQUE=($(grep -Eo ';[A-Z][0-9]+\.[0-9]+;' tst.csv | sort | uniq -u));
for i in ${UNIQUE[@]}; do
    grep $i tst.csv;
done
```

This produces:

```
Jer;B;;C15.1;;
```

Comment: My result in the terminal is `Binary file x.csv matches`

Comment: What is the output of `file x.csv`? I assumed it was a ASCII text file.

Comment: Oh yes sorry my file was corrupted it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an array for each room
2. Read file line by line, extract room and person name and add this name to corresponding room array
3. After you red all lines check if any room array has only one element, if so this guy is alone, get his name and find it in file and display that line.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, you can check if someone else is using the room with

```sh
if test $(grep ";$room;" -c file) -eq 1
```

it will enter the if condition only if there is exactly one room matching, thanks to the regex. the `-c` option counts the lines that the regex returns

So for your example, if you want to echo lines only if their room is unique, you can do

```sh
input="collaborateurs.csv"
while read line; do
    room=$(echo $line | cut -d \; -f 4)
    if test $(grep ";$room;" -c file) -eq 1
        then echo "$line"
    fi
done < "$input"
```

*Note: this is assuming that no other field can contain a room identification number. If this is possible, you'll need another regex, like `.*;.*;.*;$room;.*;`*

I hope this helps!

Comment: No I would also like to see  who's in this room if possible

Comment: So the output is `Jer;B;;C15.1;;`, so you could either parse the output with something like awk or modify the loop to have each variable. For instance, `while IFS=; read -r name firstname phone room email` will put each field in the corresponding variable